# Can't understand why Google Translate REST API returns HTTP 400

Tags: groovy, apache-camel, google-translate

Using this camel route sending POST request to Google Translate API:

```
from("direct:start").
setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant('POST')).
setHeader('X-HTTP-Method-Override', constant('GET')).
setBody(constant('q=Hello')).                                                                                                                                                                                                           
log(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'sourcingtool', '${body}').
to("https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=${api_key}&target=fr").
to('stream:out')
```

For some reason getting HTTP 400. 
Who is seeing some problem in the request?

**UPDATE 1**
When I'm using `curl` and sending similar request, everyting works like a charm:

`curl -XPOST -H "X-HTTP-Method-Override:GET" --data "q=Hello" "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=MY_API_KEY&target=fr"`

Comment: Its a 400 error. Did you check if the url sent in the camel request actually translates to the one in the curl. what is ${api_key}?

Comment: Well, yes I checked. It looks good. When I replace POST to GET, remove body and append it to QUERY_STRING - everything works fine. However, I need POST as my query (`q=` parameter) could be big (Google allows up to 5K chars).

Comment: `api_key` is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was simple. I just needed to explicitly set CONTENT_TYPE:

```
from("direct:start").
setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant('POST')).
setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant('application/x-www-form-urlencoded')). // this one did a trick
setHeader('X-HTTP-Method-Override', constant('GET')).
setBody(constant('q=Hello')).                                                                                                                                                                                                           
log(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'sourcingtool', '${body}').
to("https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=${api_key}&target=fr").
to('stream:out')
```